# How to map over a record with heterogeneous element types

Tags: purescript

I have a record that I want to map over. The record elements are of heterogenious types but of higher kinded types

```
data U a = U a
data V a = V a

data R a = R {x :: a Int, y :: a String }

fromU2V (U a) = V a

r1 = R { x: U 1, y: U "yo!" }

map f (R { x: x, y: y }) = R { x: f x, y: f y }

r2 = map fromU2V r1 
-- :type r2 => R V
```

How can I get this done? The code above gives me an error on the line

```
map f (R { x: x, y: y }) = R { x: f x, y: f y }
                                          ^^^

    Could not match type
        String
    with type
        Int
```

I assume that the function `f` is inferred to be of a to specific type here

PS: the code is in Purescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Higher-rank types such as this `map` cannot usually be inferred (at least, not right now). I think you will need to add a type signature:

```
map :: forall f g. (forall a. f a -> g a) -> R f -> R g
map f (R { x: x, y: y }) = R { x: f x, y: f y }
```

Or, equivalently, using the [`NaturalTransformation` type synonym](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/2.3.0/docs/Data.NaturalTransformation#t:NaturalTransformation) defined in the Prelude:

```
map :: forall f g. (f ~> g) -> R f -> R g
```